# AWS S3 Redirects are not redirecting to expected items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-redirect

The short story: I need to redirect a bunch of URLs to new URLs because old 'cached' urls are coming up on search engines and getting 404s now. So i set up a test S3 bucket as a static web host to test the options of doing this, there are about 40 URLs so the "custom XML" redirect definition seems like the most efficient way (I understand there is a limit of 50 redirects using this method).

In the docs ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html ) there is no example of doing specific page-to-page URL redirect - although it is implied - and explicitly done in other methods.

Below is my example - and it does not work, all the expected redirects do not redirect.

** as a second method - I edited the "meta" of each item, to explicitly do the redirect... no luck there either

I am clearly missing something. Please, any help is greatly appreciated.

My sample layout - hopefully "clear" in intent:

[image]

My sample in action:

```
https://sa-james-sandbox.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bad/bad.html
```

My Example Redirects:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>/bad/bad.html</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyWith>/good/good.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>/moved/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyWith>/foldermoved.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>/doc/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>/document/</ReplaceKeyWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

The Result form hitting "bad" - expected redirect to "good"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the S3 website endpoint in order to make the redirection functional.

http://sa-james-sandbox.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bad/bad.html

Comment: thanks that helped. At lease for the "metatag" way of doing it.
any insight into the RoutingRules way of redirecting a specific page to a specific other page... the problem with the meta is it gets wiped when i push an update (granted that shouldn't happen with a dead page but...) the RoutingRules would let me specify a file of redirects...better when i have so many

Comment: It's still redirected to `good.html`, which means the routing rule is taking effect.

Comment: hum yes it is - in firefox... But no it's not - in chrome
(and not in FF if i open in private browser..) Somehow, it's remembering the previous redirect